# Getting 2 errors while I try to build Signed APK of my React Native App

Tags: android, react-native, android-keystore, signed-apk

When I try to build a signed apk with Android Studio or from Terminal I get these error:

> Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' property '$1' during up-to-date check.
>
> Could not list contents of '/Users/khalil/ReactNative/QRApp/QRApp/node_modules/metro/node_modules/sane/node_modules/.bin/watch'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.

From the terminal the command I am using is this:

```
sudo ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

I have made this many times with other apps but this is a new app and I think I am missing something to the new app creation about the keyStore or something else.